# Why does Pandas column slicing give varying results based on column naming?

Tags: python, pandas

After running into a memory error when performing dataframe merges, I found a rather peculiar behaviour in pandas column slicing. Below an example of the behaviour observed. The dataframes are identical, except for the columns being renamed for `df4` as opposed to `df3`.

However, when column slicing the frames, for one of them, the numerical columns are duplicated, whereas for the other the slicing behaves as expected.

Has any Pandas wizard on here experienced this before? And if so, is there any handle on what triggers the behaviour, so it can be avoided altogether.

```
df3
Out[1138]: 
              A    B       C       D
Date                                
2017-03-31  NaN  NaN  2.9511  2.9511
2017-03-30  NaN  NaN  2.9009  2.9009
2017-03-29  NaN  NaN  2.9356  2.9356
2017-03-28  NaN  NaN  2.9008  2.9008
2017-03-27  NaN  NaN  2.8576  2.8576

df4
Out[1139]: 
           Feb16 Mar16   Mar17   Mar17
Date                                  
2017-03-31   NaN   NaN  2.9511  2.9511
2017-03-30   NaN   NaN  2.9009  2.9009
2017-03-29   NaN   NaN  2.9356  2.9356
2017-03-28   NaN   NaN  2.9008  2.9008
2017-03-27   NaN   NaN  2.8576  2.8576

df3[df3.columns]
Out[1140]: 
              A    B       C       D
Date                                
2017-03-31  NaN  NaN  2.9511  2.9511
2017-03-30  NaN  NaN  2.9009  2.9009
2017-03-29  NaN  NaN  2.9356  2.9356
2017-03-28  NaN  NaN  2.9008  2.9008
2017-03-27  NaN  NaN  2.8576  2.8576

df4[df4.columns]
Out[1141]: 
           Feb16 Mar16   Mar17   Mar17   Mar17   Mar17
Date                                                  
2017-03-31   NaN   NaN  2.9511  2.9511  2.9511  2.9511
2017-03-30   NaN   NaN  2.9009  2.9009  2.9009  2.9009
2017-03-29   NaN   NaN  2.9356  2.9356  2.9356  2.9356
2017-03-28   NaN   NaN  2.9008  2.9008  2.9008  2.9008
2017-03-27   NaN   NaN  2.8576  2.8576  2.8576  2.8576
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 columns with identical names in a `dataframe` to begin with?

Comment: What I meant was to ask if it might have something to do with your question, but from your answer I understand that the problem araises when they are not truely identical.

Comment: IMO this problem is introduced by the attempt to overwrite the columns of a dataframe with a list of non-unique names. This is - to speak shortly - kind of misuse, because the column name should be a unique identifier of the column of a dataframe.

Comment: As far as I understand the data I have, it should not have identical columns whatsoever, but after rechecking, there are indeed a couple. Interesting! Thanks, both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example why I think that this behaviour is introduced by giving several columns the same name:

creating example df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({x: np.random.random(2) for x in ['A1', 'A2']})

         A1        A2
0  0.217047  0.224265
1  0.454130  0.304111
```

column indexing as requested works:

```
df[df.columns]

         A1        A2
0  0.217047  0.224265
1  0.454130  0.304111
```

renaming columns to non-unique list:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str[0]

          A         A
0  0.217047  0.224265
1  0.454130  0.304111
```

reproduced error from question post:

```
df[df.columns]

          A         A         A         A
0  0.217047  0.224265  0.217047  0.224265
1  0.454130  0.304111  0.454130  0.304111
```